# Windows 10 Getting Windows Ready Message

Tags: windows-10

This is the third time I've seen this today for this Windows 10 machine, in addition to it needing to install updates.  Is this normal and how can I get computer to stop showing me this screen?  The major issue is that it takes about 45 minutes each time this screen shows up, all because of a restart.  This seems very odd.

Thanks.

Message:

> Getting windows ready don't turn off your computer

Comment: Does it always take about 45 minutes? Never forever, it always finishes? Does this issue happen every single time you restart, no exception?